# Close Popup modal after form is valid(all validation) in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, angular4-forms

we used data-dismiss in html form it's working fine. but the modal close every time when click submit button weather form is valid or invalid

**Html code**

```
<form #AddAirlineuser="ngForm">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">CREATE PROFILE</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Name</label>
        <p><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" aria-label="..." ngModel></p>
        <label>Email</label>
        <p><input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" aria-label="..." ngModel></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click) = "Btn_AddNewAirline(AddAirlineuser.valid,AddAirlineuser.value)">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**TypeScript code**

```
Btn_AddNewAirline(formstatus: any,data:any){
    let AirlineData: any = {
        name: data.name,
        email: data.email
    };
    if(formstatus){
        // TODO code form status is valid 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try by changing `type="button"` for `Submit`. Also better if you can create stackblitz.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to change input type as "submit" to "button". i got same error, the popup modal close before form valid

Comment: please create stackblitz and share url here.